# Try-Catch and Delete[] issue

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, delete-operator

I'm having a bit of a problem with a try-catch situation, here goes the code (it's pretty simple):

```
struct Something
{
  int A, B, C;
  Something()
  {
    A = B = C = 0;
  }
  ~Something()
  {
    cout << "Destructor " << endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Something * s = new Something;

  //Something * s = new Something[5];

  try
  {
    delete[] s;
  }
  catch(exception& e)
  {
    delete s;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

What I intend to do is to first try to delete the pointer as an array, if it fails, make a simple delete.

So, when I first try it with an array of 'Something's (as in the commented line), itr worked perfectly. But when I try it as it is now, I get a horrible error.

Any ideas?

Comment: why are you trying to delete it as an array first? that likely could cause undefined behavior.

Comment: it would help to switch the order?

Comment: no, it will just cause the same problems. what you are attempting to do is a bad idea.

Answer (score 8):

What your trying to do is neither legal C++ nor does it make sense.

An allocation with `new` must be followed by a deletion with `delete`, and an allocation with `new[]` by `delete[]`; this must happen precisely like that, and everything else is undefined behaviour.

You cannot "try and see if you wrote correct code". Exceptions signal exceptional *runtime* behaviour, but your error is a static, compile-time error that cannot be *handled*, but must be *fixed*.

However, there should never be a point in your code where you *don't know* what a given pointer means! Since the language is statically typed, you should in principle always have knowledge of the involved types. And if you want to pass objects around (possibly polymorphically), then anything that requires dynamic allocation should be wrapped in its own manager class (like `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`).

Comment: This code is actually just a small part I extract from a SmartPointer class (with templates) I'm implementing. So the idea is: I get a address memory (T \*) and when is out of scope, I delete it. But, I really dont know if that address was created with a new or a new[], so there goes the 'guessing' part.
(and \*please\* dont tell to use RAII)

Comment: @julio.alegria: Take a look at how `unique_ptr` is implemented. The key is to have a suitable deleter, which you may abstract, and which is determined at instantiation time. But no matter how you skin this cat, you cannot get around knowing what sort of pointer you have. There's no such thing as a "random pointer" in C++ whose semantics you have to guess.

Comment: @julio.alegria: Use RAII. Sorry, but it is the only way to write a correct program in C++ without painful levels of code duplication. What smart pointer behaviour are you looking for that isn't already available in the standard library?

Comment: @julio.alegria, that's what reference counters are for.  Use a pointer to int or a pointer to another class that contains an int, and increment, decrement as needed.  Check out More Effective C++ by Meyers.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting a pointer as an array (or vica versa) is incorrect and undefined. It won't throw an exception.

You should consider [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). For example, create a class which contains the pointer as a member. The constructor allocates the memory, and the destructor deletes it.

Then you've got a few options:

(1) Have two constructors, one for a single item and one for an array. Place a boolean in the class that holds whether the pointer points to one item or an array, and check this on destruction and call the appropriate delete function.

(2) Make your class a template class that takes a boolean template parameter and resolve this choice at compile time.

Comment: there have to be a solution without using libraries.
Its not always good to be a library dependent

Comment: @julio.alegria: "library dependent?" There's no reason to avoid using a library so long as it is supported on your platform of interest and does the expected job. And worst-comes-to-worst, if you can't use the C++ standard library or Boost, you can just write a smart pointer yourself.

Comment: @julio.alegria: You don't need a library to implement RAII.

Comment: I meant that something is better to learn how to do something (even if its hard) before just using it. Otherwise why dont we just learn to use STL instead of learning all those hard data structures. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

You completely misunderstand the semantics of `try`/`catch`. They don't catch errors, they catch *exceptions*. You can only rely on an exception being created if you throw it yourself or do something that's guaranteed to throw an exception. Calling `delete` on a pointer allocated with `new[]` is not guaranteed to throw an exception, in fact, it's not guaranteed to do anything specific.

Answer (score 0):

So my c++ skills are rusty but delete[] is called where you've called new[].  You haven't called new[] in your example.

Comment: thats why I'm using try-catch

Comment: I see what you are doing, but the rule is that you free what you malloc you delete what you new and you delete[] what you new[].  I think it will depend on the implementation as to what results when you deviate from the rules.